# Google analytics insert method not working?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am working on the Google analytics API where I want to insert the goal conversion from my chatbot application using API to GA. I have been trying it but it shows the 401 error where it says Login required. I been passing API key in headers.

Can anyone suggest where exactly I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please clarify what API methods you're using?

Comment: I am using the insert method.

Comment: check your scopes. insert requires https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit